# Is it possible to communicate with a laptop (or other device) connected with the wifi hotspot?

Tags: wifi-hotspot

Could I connect a device to my phone's hotspot and have the phone and device communicate over wifi? I'm intending to have a raspberry pi connect to my phone so I can SSH into it on the go.

Comment: @beeshyams if not in the official repo, then [here in mine](https://apt.izzysoft.de/fdroid/index/apk/de.eidottermihi.raspicheck). In the official repo it's stuck at v1.8.0 from 5/2016; in mine it has v1.8.7 from 2 days ago. No idea why F-Droid stopped updating it.

Comment: @beeshyams The app from Play and my repo can be "cross-updated" (same signature). I have not tested the app: no raspberry, I only have 2 bananas (BananaPi) and didn't check if it works with them as well (it should for most things, but I felt no requirement for the app yet).

Comment: Thanks, @beeshyams – though it's less than 1/3 of what's in the main repo :) // Btw: Do you know whether *RasPi Check* works in Hotspot mode? I've never played with either. Also, the Raspi needs to connect to that hotspot first, ideally automatically when in reach (or at least when in reach and its "home network" is not available). "I'm intending to have a raspberry pi connect to my phone" could be read like "make it connect so I can …", and OP wants to SSH into it for other reasons then just doing some status checks. So OP might rather looking for a "connector app", however that should work.

Comment: @beeshyams While that app is interesting, it doesn't solve my issue. I'm looking for a way to connect to my pi, which is connected to my phones wifi hotspot rather than a common access point.

Comment: OK, as it *is* already connected to the "local hotspot", the question is rather "how to access a device connected to the local hotspot" – as the title already suggests (not "connect a device" as the body phrases it). The app @beeshyams suggested most likely assumes that part already solved. I've never worked with local hotspot, so I cannot tell; but I'd assume that if you know the IP of the Pi (the "I Pi"? ;) you should be able to point an [SSH client](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admin_sshclients#group_387) to that. Have you tried?

Comment: @Izzy Another issue is that I do not know how to get the ip address of something connected to the hotspot. Though I suppose that should just be a simple ifconfig, but it's difficult to access my pi when it isn't connected to anything. (No screen, relying on ssh)

Comment: That's usually done by an ARP scan. Take a look at e.g. [Network Assistant](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hackutils.network): the screenshot "Local Hosts" shows it can list all devices in the same network. That should work to find the IP of the Pi. [LanXChange](https://apt.izzysoft.de/fdroid/index/apk/de.tobifleig.lxc) might also be worth a look in this context: installed on both the Pi and your Android device, the two should easily find each other.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, and it's easy. I know this is an old post, but it's had 80 views in 6 years, so maybe people are looking for help.

I live in the middle of nowhere, where the Internet is only available on my phone. So I connect all my devices - TV, Amazon Fire stick, laptop, media server and data server - to the hotspot. I do scripting on the phone, but I am actually on my PC connected using SSH. On the phone, I just have Termux and openssh installed. Follow [this procedure.](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Remote_Access#SSH) After it's set up and you have completed the key exchange, you need to set a password. On the phone, type:

`passwd`

and choose a password (you'll be asked to enter it twice). Still on the phone, type:

`whoami`

This will give you your UID which you will need to enter in the ssh command on the other device. It's something akin to u0_a123 on a Samsung phone.

Then, all you need to do on the phone when you want to connect, is type:

`sshd`

On the PC, you need to determine the current IP of the phone. On Linux, you can just copy and paste this in a terminal window:

`route -n | grep wlp | grep 'UG[ \t]' | awk '{print $2}'`

I'm not a fan of Windows, but you can always run traceroute to any site to see the IP appear towards the top of the list.

Connect to the phone using:

`ssh UID@<IP of phone> -p 8022`

When you want to disconnect, stop the ssh server on the phone with:

`pkill sshd`

in the Termux screen.